# Problema al hacer PUT con imagen en Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy haciendo pruebas con la API que acabo de desarrollar y me da problemas al hacer PUT.

Yo tengo mi modelo;

```
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    logo=models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    banner=models.ImageField(upload_to="media")    
    published=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Después tengo mi serializador:

```
    class Meta:
        model=restaurant
        fields='__all__'
```

Y por último mi vista:

```
@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def restaurant_detail_view(request,pk):
    
    if request.method=="GET":
        rest=restaurant.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
        rest_serializer=restaurantSerializers(rest)
        return Response (rest_serializer.data)

    elif request.method=="PUT":
        rest=restaurant.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
        rest_serializer=restaurantSerializers(rest,data=request.data)
        if rest_serializer.is_valid():
            rest_serializer.save()
            return Response(rest_serializer.data)
        return Response(rest_serializer.errors)
```

Cuando desde POSTMAN hago un PUT a un restaurante existente, me da el siguiente error:

```
{
    "logo": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ],
    "banner": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ]
}
```

Agradecería que me echaran una mano!
Gracias!!

Comment: Estas usando Pillow para poder procesar las imagenes?

Comment: Si. Descargé la librería de PyPi (pip install pillow), lo que no se si hay que importarla en algún fichero o internamente Django ya lo hace